# glmmTMB-posthoctest-lsmeans

Tags: glmmtmb

all.

> I've fitted the following model

```
model1<-glmmTMB(total~treatm+(1|factor1)+(1|factor2)+(1|factor3), data=mydata1, family=nbinom1)
```

and I performed a post-hoc test like follows:

```
model1multcomp<-lsmeans(model1,pairwise~treatm)
```

and it worked fine
but,
for the following model:

```
model2<-glmmTMB(total~treatm+(1|factor1)+(1|factor2)+(1|factor3), data=mydata2, family=nbinom1)
```

when I tried to perform the same post hoc test
`model2multcomp<-lsmeans(model2,pairwise~treatm)`,
I'm getting the error message below:

```
Error in ref.grid(object = list(obj = list(par = c(beta = 0, beta = 0,  :
```

Can't handle an object of class  “glmmTMB” 
 Use help("models", package = "lsmeans") for information on supported models.

I'm surprised that this worked a first time and not at a second time, so that  I come ask for your help.
Thanks in advance for your help

> Notes:
>   treatm is a grouping factor with 7 levels;
>   factor1 is a grouping factor with 11 levels;
>   factor2 is a grouping factor with 6 levels;
>   factor3 is a grouping factor with 8 levels

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the error message refers to `ref.grid` instead of `ref_grid` indicates that you have an ancient version of **lsmeans** installed. You should install an updated version, then it has a better chance of working.

Comment: Thank you so much